# Compress image android

Tags: android, image, scaling, image-scaling, image-compression

I have an app where you can take a picture or select an image from the gallery.
The photo taken/selected once must be uploaded to the server. 
My question is, as there are different devices with different sizes and resolutions, should the compressed image be loaded to the original size on the server or should it be scaled up and then compressed? 
 What is the best way for scale an image for all device?

Now I'm using this algorithm when user take a photo by the camera or by gallery

```
private void setPic() throws IOException {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, options);
        // Calculate inSampleSize
        int sampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 720, 720);
        Log.d("UserPanel", "Samplesize: " + sampleSize);
        Log.d("SquareImage", ""+image.getWidth());
        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, options);
        Log.d("UserPanel", "Bytebitmap: " + bitmap.getByteCount());
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

        int rotationAngle = 0;
        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (float) bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, options.outWidth, options.outHeight, matrix, true);
        Log.d("UserPanel", "Bytebitmaprotate: " + rotatedBitmap.getByteCount());
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), rotatedBitmap, imageFileName, "");
        File fdelete = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        if (fdelete.delete()) Log.d("UserPanel", "Delete");
        imageToServer = getStringImage(rotatedBitmap);
    }
```

This is calculateSampleSize

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        Log.d("UserPanel", "Width: " + width + " height: " + height);
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

To compress the image I fixed a size of 100KB

```
private String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        int compressQuality = 100;
        int streamLength = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        do{
            ByteArrayOutputStream bmpStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d("compressBitmap", "Quality: " + compressQuality);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpStream);
            byte[] bmpPicByteArray = bmpStream.toByteArray();
            streamLength = bmpPicByteArray.length;
            compressQuality -= 5;
            Log.d("compressBitmap", "Size: " + streamLength/1024+" kb");
        }while (streamLength >= 100000);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        Log.d("UserPanel", "Bytebitmap compress: " + imageBytes.length);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to compress image using this class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class CompressImage {

    Context mContext;

    public CompressImage(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public String compressImage(String imageUri) throws IOException {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        if(filePath == null)
        {
            filePath = imageUri;
        }
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = imageUri;
        File oldfile = new File(imageUri);
        if (oldfile.exists()) {
            oldfile.delete();
        }
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;

    }

    public String getFilename() throws IOException {
//        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
//        if (!file.exists()) {
//            file.mkdirs();
//        }
//        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "twice_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ".jpg", /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
        );

//        ChatRoomFragment.picturePath= image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image.getAbsolutePath();

    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }


}
```